# WebSerial API on WINDOWS - "DOMException: Failed to open serial port."

Tags: angular, windows, google-chrome, serial-port, usbserial

I am trying to use the [WebSerial API](https://wicg.github.io/serial/) on Windows after it worked fine on macOS with no problem. The device was plugged into a Macbook and no extra action was required. When I connect the device (USB to Serial adapter) to a Windows machine and access my Angular website using Google Chrome, I get this error:

> DOMException: Failed to open serial port.

When I access `chrome://device-log/` I see this error:

> [USB][ERROR][17:09:20] Failed to read descriptor from node connection:
> A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)

Below is the code that I am using, and an error is displayed when code runs line `await this.scale.open({ baudRate: 9600 });`.

```
const VENDOR_ID = 1027;
const PRODUCT_ID = 24577;

...

  let button = document.getElementById('request-device');
    button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
      try {

        this.scale = await navigator.serial.requestPort({
          filters: [{
            usbProductId: PRODUCT_ID,
            usbVendorId: VENDOR_ID
          }]
        });
    
        await this.scale.open({ baudRate: 9600 }); //ERROR HAPPENS HERE

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    });
  }
```

There are two similar questions here on for Ubuntu but no answers or solutions were given. ([Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63112645/webserial-api-device-cannot-open-port-on-ubuntu) and [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64378562/web-serial-api-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-failed-to-open-serial-port))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a driver issue.

Most old models USB to Serial adapters are presenting problems on Windows 10. After trying several drivers, I found [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8x55VWR5Ijc&ab_channel=AhhearPOV) that solved my problem.

It is linked to a Youtube video in a language that I do not understand. However, the steps are easy to follow. After downloading the driver and following the steps, it works just fine.